# Transition and Transform in tailwind css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make it so that when the user presses the input box, it will slowly transition the input box to the bottom of the screen and the h1 to the top left of the screen to make space for chats between the user and some ai feature. They are both moving to the correct positions, but they are jumping into position instead of smoothly moving into position. I'm not sure what exactly the issue is but it has to be something with the way I've set up the transition and transforms. Also noticed that when the input box moves to the bottom, its size changes to almost the full width of the screen and I cant figure out how to stop that.

Heres the code:

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Header from '@/components/Header';
import SendChatButton from '@/components/buttons/SendChatButton';

export default function Home() {
  const [isInputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isFormFixed, setFormFixed] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const clearInput = () => setInputValue('');
  
  return (
    <main>
      <section className='p-4 pt-32'>
        <div className={`transition ease-linear duration-800 ${isInputFocused ? 'fixed top-16 left-0 text-xl' : 'static top-0 left-0 text-6xl'}`}>
          <h1 className='font-bold'>
            Your very own<br /> personal designer
          </h1>
          <h2 className={`text-xl mt-6 ${isInputFocused ? 'hidden' : ''}`}>Makes finding outfits so much easier</h2>
        </div>
        <form
          className={`mt-6 flex shadow-md ${isFormFixed ? 'fixed bottom-12 left-4 w-11/12 transition-transform duration-1000 ease-in-out transform translate-y-0' : 'static w-11/12 transition-transform duration-1000 ease-in-out transform -translate-y-12'}`}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder='Message your personal designer...'
            className="p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md block w-full text-sm outline-none"
            onFocus={() => {
              setInputFocused(true);
              setFormFixed(true);
            }}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
          />
          <SendChatButton inputValue={inputValue} clearInput={clearInput}/>
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Heading `h1` and `h2` Elements, Instead of switching between `fixed` and `static`, use `transform` to move the header. This way, you can smoothly transition its position without changing its layout property (`position`), which cannot be transitioned smoothly.

For the Input Box, Make sure that its width doesn't depend on its position status (`fixed` vs. `static`). Set a specific `max-width` or ensure the parent's width remains constant.

Remove `isFormFixed` since it seems redundant, your form's position can be directly controlled with `isInputFocused`.

Apply `transition-all` for smoother transitions of multiple properties.

Change the positioning of your header and form to use `transform` and `opacity` for smoother transitions.

Make sure that the parent element of the absolute items (`<section>`) has a `relative` position to provide a reference for the absolute positioning.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [isInputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState(false);

  const clearInput = () => setInputValue('');
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  // Additional state is not necessary as the form's position is solely based on isInputFocused
  return (
    <main>
      <section className='p-4 pt-32 relative'> {/* Ensure this is relative to position children absolutely */}
        <div className={`transition-all ease-linear duration-800 transform ${isInputFocused ? 'absolute top-4 left-4 text-xl' : 'absolute top-32 left-4 text-6xl'}`}>
          <h1 className='font-bold'>
            Your very own<br /> personal designer
          </h1>
          <h2 className={`text-xl mt-6 transition-opacity duration-800 ${isInputFocused ? 'opacity-0' : 'opacity-100'}`}>Makes finding outfits so much easier</h2>
        </div>
        <form
          className={`mt-6 flex shadow-md transition-all duration-1000 ease-in-out ${isInputFocused ? 'fixed bottom-12 left-4 w-11/12' : 'absolute -translate-y-12 left-4 w-11/12'}`} // Use absolute for initial state for smooth transition
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder='Message your personal designer...'
            className="p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md block w-full text-sm outline-none"
            onFocus={() => {
              setInputFocused(true);
            }}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
          />
          <SendChatButton inputValue={inputValue} clearInput={clearInput}/>
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```